# How to optimize realm.allobjects(class) in Android

Tags: realm

I want to use Realm to replace SqLite in Android to store a list of classes, my code is very simple as below.

```
public class MyRealmObject extends RealmObject {

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }
    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    private String field;
    ...
}


List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList();

Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(this);
for(MyRealmObject realm : realm.allobjects(MyRealmObject.class)) {
  myObjects.add(new MyObject(realm));
}

realm.close();
return myObjects;
```

However, its performance is actually slower than a simple SqlLite table on my tested device, am I using it the wrong way? Is there any optimization tricks?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to wrap all your `RealmObjects` in the `MyObject` class?. Especially copying the entire result set means you will loose the benefit of using Realm, namely that it doesn't copy data unless needed to.

`RealmResults` implements the `List` interface so you should be able to use the two interchangeably.

```
List<MyRealmObject> myObjects;

Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(this);
myObjects = realm.allObjects(MyRealmObject.class();
return myObjects;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about that as well, but can I still use myObjects even after I call realm.close()? According to Realm doc, we should call realm.close() asap to avoid leaking memory. But I need to use the returned myObjects throughout the app lifecycle.

Comment: Btw, even without casting from RealmObjects to MyOjbects, using realm.allOjbects(class) is only 20% to 30% faster than SqlLite at best on my test device, is this expected?

Comment: Realm is a zero-copy database, which means you should keep the database open for as long as you read data from it. That normally means as long as any activity is open. You can use onCreate/onDestroy to make sure this works correctly. Realm caches open instances internally, so it won't accidentally be closed if following that pattern.

Comment: Without seeing your test case it is hard to tell if that is expected. It sounds a little low though.